# What does it mean for a Coxeter system to be of "spherical" type?

Tags: group-theory, reflection, coxeter-groups

In the theorem of the paper [Sur les valeurs propres de la transformation de Coxeter](https://eudml.org/doc/142377) the author uses in the main theorem the term "spherical" to refer to a property that Coxeter systems $(W,S)$ can have. What exactly does that term mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\Gamma$ be a Coxeter graph and let $(W,S)$ be the Coxeter system of $\Gamma$. We say $\Gamma$ is $\textit{of spherical type}$ if $W_{\Gamma}$ is finite.

Note that if $\Gamma_1,\ldots, \Gamma_{\ell}$ are the connected components of $\Gamma$, then $W=W_{\Gamma_1}\times \cdots \times W_{\Gamma_{\ell}}$.
In this case, $\Gamma$ is of spherical type if and only if each of its connected component is of spherical type.

Some properties are:

1. A Coxeter graph $\Gamma$ is of spherical type if and only if the symmetric bilinear form $b:V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is positive definite, where $V$ is a representation space of $W$.
2. The connected spherical type Coxeter graphs are precisely the following:

$\hspace{6cm}$
[image: coxeter-graph-spherical-type]

Note: the image has been taken from Mike Davis' slides on "Examples of Groups: Coxeter Groups".